# Keras raises an exception on loading a lambda layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, exception, keras

Saving and loading a model in TensorFlow 2.3.1...

```
import tensorflow as tf

model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (81,), dtype = 'uint8'), 
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tf.keras.backend.one_hot, arguments={'num_classes': 10}, output_shape=(81, 10)),
])

tf.keras.models.save_model(model1, './model')
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model')
model2.summary()
```

causes a rather long exception, quoted in full below. It seems to be the Lambda layer that causes issues; save-loading works fine without it. I've tried adding `custom_objects={'one_hot' : tf.keras.backend.one_hot}` and suchlike to the load call, but it doesn't fix it. I'd be very grateful if anyone had a workaround for this.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    200     try:
--> 201       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    202     except (TypeError, ValueError):

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-77668ee9d9b2> in <module>
      7 
      8 tf.keras.models.save_model(model1, './model')
----> 9 model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model', custom_objects={'tf.keras.backend.one_hot' : tf.keras.backend.one_hot})
     10 model2.summary()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, options)
    185     if isinstance(filepath, six.string_types):
    186       loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)
--> 187       return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
    188 
    189   raise IOError(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in load(path, compile, options)
    119 
    120   model = tf_load.load_internal(
--> 121       path, options=options, loader_cls=KerasObjectLoader)
    122 
    123   # pylint: disable=protected-access

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in load_internal(export_dir, tags, options, loader_cls)
    631       try:
    632         loader = loader_cls(object_graph_proto, saved_model_proto, export_dir,
--> 633                             ckpt_options)
    634       except errors.NotFoundError as err:
    635         raise FileNotFoundError(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    192     self._models_to_reconstruct = []
    193 
--> 194     super(KerasObjectLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    195 
    196     # Now that the node object has been fully loaded, and the checkpoint has

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in __init__(self, object_graph_proto, saved_model_proto, export_dir, ckpt_options)
    128       self._concrete_functions[name] = _WrapperFunction(concrete_function)
    129 
--> 130     self._load_all()
    131     self._restore_checkpoint()
    132 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in _load_all(self)
    219 
    220     # Finish setting up layers and models. See function docstring for more info.
--> 221     self._finalize_objects()
    222 
    223   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in _finalize_objects(self)
    528 
    529     # Initialize graph networks, now that layer dependencies have been resolved.
--> 530     self._reconstruct_all_models()
    531 
    532   def _unblock_model_reconstruction(self, layer_id, layer):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in _reconstruct_all_models(self)
    546       all_initialized_models.add(model_id)
    547       model, layers = self.model_layer_dependencies[model_id]
--> 548       self._reconstruct_model(model_id, model, layers)
    549       self._add_object_graph_edges(self._proto.nodes[model_id], model_id)
    550       _finalize_config_layers([model])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in _reconstruct_model(self, model_id, model, layers)
    576               dtype=layers[0].dtype,
    577               name=layers[0].name + '_input'))
--> 578       model.__init__(layers, name=config['name'])
    579       if not model.inputs:
    580         first_layer = self._get_child_layer_node_ids(model_id, model.name)[0]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in __init__(self, layers, name)
    140         layers = [layers]
    141       for layer in layers:
--> 142         self.add(layer)
    143 
    144   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    219       # If the model is being built continuously on top of an input layer:
    220       # refresh its output.
--> 221       output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
    222       if len(nest.flatten(output_tensor)) != 1:
    223         raise ValueError(SINGLE_LAYER_OUTPUT_ERROR_MSG)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    924     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
    925       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
--> 926                                                 input_list)
    927 
    928     # Maintains info about the `Layer.call` stack.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1115           try:
   1116             with ops.enable_auto_cast_variables(self._compute_dtype_object):
-> 1117               outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
   1118 
   1119           except errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError as e:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training)
    901     with backprop.GradientTape(watch_accessed_variables=True) as tape,\
    902         variable_scope.variable_creator_scope(_variable_creator):
--> 903       result = self.function(inputs, **kwargs)
    904     self._check_variables(created_variables, tape.watched_variables())
    905     return result

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    203       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a
    204       # TypeError, when given unexpected types.  So we need to catch both.
--> 205       result = dispatch(wrapper, args, kwargs)
    206       if result is not OpDispatcher.NOT_SUPPORTED:
    207         return result

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use the [`tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.CategoryEncoding`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/CategoryEncoding) layer.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (81,), dtype=tf.int32), 
    tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.CategoryEncoding(
        max_tokens=(10), output_mode='count'), # or 'binary'
])

tf.keras.models.save_model(model1, './model')
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model')
model2.summary()

inp = tf.random.uniform((1, 81), 0, 10, dtype=tf.int32)

model2(inp)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32, 
    numpy=array([[ 7., 11.,  5.,  6., 10.,  5.,  5., 12., 10., 10.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with input type uint8, which I am using. Is there a way to cast the data without another Lambda layer?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I don't want to cast the data to int32 before pushing it to the GPU, because it will take 4x the bandwidth. The only way I know of to convert it inside the model is with a Lambda layer with a cast in...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using a lambda layer.
A possible workaround is **defining a custom lamda function outside the model and using it inside the lambda layer**.

Here is the updated code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def custom_one_hot(x):
    return tf.keras.backend.one_hot(x, num_classes=10) #or tf.one_hot(x, depth=10)

model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(81,), dtype='uint8'),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(custom_one_hot, output_shape=(81, 10)),
])

tf.keras.models.save_model(model1, './model')
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model')
model2.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_8"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lambda_8 (Lambda)           (None, 81, 10)            0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Important:** each time we want to use the model we will need to define it before loading the model. Otherwise will run into an error:

```
NameError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lambda_8" (type Lambda).

name 'custom_one_hot' is not defined
```

To resolve this issue, we need to ensure that the custom function is defined before loading the model. The code defining the custom function used inside the lambda layer should always be executed before loading the saved models.